# React Native - Handle session timeout after any api call

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a complex react-native application and I'm using .net api for backend. When session timeout occurs on api side, I want to automatically logout the user and return to login page. But I can't use dispatch in the class that I'm doing api call. Because its not a component or a redux file. To navigate to the login page I need to dispatch some actions. Is there a way to do is? If I use Redux-Toolkit, does it work? I am looking for an easier solution because start using Redux toolkit in the project is a big effort for me right now.

Here is my project's structure:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"But I can't use dispatch in the class that I'm doing api call."
why not, you can dispatch everywhere,

this is my code, you can try it

```
//this is store
export const store = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware)
);

//import to use anywhere
import {store} from '../redux/store'
store.dispatch(setUser(null)); // call when session out
```

Comment: Its much more easy than I think! Thank you so much.